# Nested Flexbox Items Not Expanding to Fill Parent When Scrollable

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to create the following layout using CSS3 flexboxes but have hit a stumbling block.

The layout has 3 outer rows, with the "header" and "footer" being fixed height. The middle flexes to fill the available space. The middle row must also be scrollable.

Within the flexible middle, there are 3 columns, with the left and right being fixed width and the middle flexing to fill the available space.

See what I have so far here: http://codepen.io/Samih/pen/yCHaI

Everything was going swimmingly, but in all 3 main browsers (chrome, firefox and IE11) scrolling down you will notice that the backgrounds/borders on the 3 columns do not extend to the full height of the parent container. Their height is maxing out at the height of the visible area instead of the full height of the container.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
section, article {
    align-self: baseline;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/HAJDs

Comment: Works in chrome and FF but not in IE11 unfortunately :/. Also do you know why this makes a difference? I don't see why it should.

Comment: @Samih: I just noticed.

Comment: Thank you! `align-self: flex-start;` works as well, but the one I originally tried because it sounds right (align-self: stretch) does not.

Comment: Also for anyone who might come by this answer in the future, `margin: auto;` was the technique that works only in chrome and firefox. The answer was since edited to `align-self: baseline;` which works in IE 11 as well as chrome and firefox.